# Why does this integer overflow occur?

Tags: .net, integer-overflow

I've wrapped a dll method that has an integer as an out parameter in a web service.
In testing I was finding that when I was expecting -1 I was getting 65,535 instead. I realised that the dll was using 16 bit integers and I was specifying the standard .NET 32bit integer when referencing the external dll in my code. this was quickly fixed by specifying a 16 bit integer and all is well.

My question is why did this happen? I could understand an overflow occuring if I was trying to fit a 32 bit integer in a 16 bit integer but I am not so sure why this happens the other way round. Clearly my understanding of this type of casting between types is a little lacking so any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 16 bit integer "-1" has all 16 bits set.  If you set the bottom 16 bits of a 32 bit integer, the value is 65,535.  For an explanation of the internal representation of negative ints, have a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_complement).

Comment: @Paul - Thanks for the explanantion and the link. Together they explained it nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This happened because of the type-casting.

You don't actually send 16-bit integers on the call stack -- they're still 32-bit.  So what the DLL returned *exactly* was:

```
0x0000ffff
```

If you cast this to e.g. `sint16`, this is `-1`, but if this is 32-bits, this is `65535`.